# multiprocessing logging using queue handler logs same line multiple times extra as number of processes when process pool is being used

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

```
# SuperFastPython.com
#https://superfastpython.com/multiprocessing-pool-logging/
# example of logging from multiple workers in the multiprocessing pool
from random import random
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import current_process
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Manager
from logging.handlers import QueueHandler
import logging


# executed in a process that performs logging
def logger_process(queue):
    # create a logger
    logger = logging.getLogger('app')
    # configure a stream handler
    logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    # log all messages, debug and up
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # report that the logger process is running
    logger.info(f'Logger process running.')
    # run forever
    while True:
        # consume a log message, block until one arrives
        message = queue.get()
        # check for shutdown
        if message is None:
            logger.info(f'Logger process shutting down.')
            break
        # log the message
        logger.handle(message)


# task to be executed in child processes
def task(queue):
    # create a logger
    logger = logging.getLogger('app')
    # add a handler that uses the shared queue
    logger.addHandler(QueueHandler(queue))
    # log all messages, debug and up
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # get the current process
    process = current_process()
    # report initial message
    logger.info(f'Child {process.name} starting.')
    # simulate doing work
    for i in range(1):
        # report a message
        logger.debug(f'Child {process.name} step {i}.')
        # block
        sleep(random())
    # report final message
    logger.info(f'Child {process.name} done.')


# protect the entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create the manager
    with Manager() as manager:
        # create the shared queue and get the proxy object
        queue = manager.Queue()
        # create a logger
        logger = logging.getLogger('app')
        # add a handler that uses the shared queue
        logger.addHandler(QueueHandler(queue))
        # log all messages, debug and up
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        # create the process pool with default configuration
        with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
            # issue a long running task to receive logging messages
            _ = pool.apply_async(logger_process, args=(queue,))
            # report initial message
            logger.info('Main process started.')
            # issue task to the process pool
            results = [pool.apply_async(task, args=(queue,)) for i in range(**1**)]
            # wait for all issued tasks to complete
            logger.info('Main process waiting...')
            for result in results:
                result.wait()
            # report final message
            logger.info('Main process done.')
            # shutdown the long running logger task
            queue.put(None)
            # close the process pool
            pool.close()
            # wait for all tasks to complete (e.g. the logger to close)
            pool.join()
```

The above code has two processes in the process pool. One for the logger process and one for the process worker.It produces output as expected below

```
Logger process running.
Main process started.
Main process waiting...
Child SpawnPoolWorker-2 starting.
Child SpawnPoolWorker-2 step 0.
Child SpawnPoolWorker-2 done.
Main process done.
Logger process shutting down.
```

Now if I change code and add extra worker, it produces extra lines

```
# SuperFastPython.com
#https://superfastpython.com/multiprocessing-pool-logging/
# example of logging from multiple workers in the multiprocessing pool
from random import random
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import current_process
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Manager
from logging.handlers import QueueHandler
import logging


# executed in a process that performs logging
def logger_process(queue):
    # create a logger
    logger = logging.getLogger('app')
    # configure a stream handler
    logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    # log all messages, debug and up
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # report that the logger process is running
    logger.info(f'Logger process running.')
    # run forever
    while True:
        # consume a log message, block until one arrives
        message = queue.get()
        # check for shutdown
        if message is None:
            logger.info(f'Logger process shutting down.')
            break
        # log the message
        logger.handle(message)


# task to be executed in child processes
def task(queue):
    # create a logger
    logger = logging.getLogger('app')
    # add a handler that uses the shared queue
    logger.addHandler(QueueHandler(queue))
    # log all messages, debug and up
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # get the current process
    process = current_process()
    # report initial message
    logger.info(f'Child {process.name} starting.')
    # simulate doing work
    for i in range(1):
        # report a message
        logger.debug(f'Child {process.name} step {i}.')
        # block
        sleep(random())
    # report final message
    logger.info(f'Child {process.name} done.')


# protect the entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create the manager
    with Manager() as manager:
        # create the shared queue and get the proxy object
        queue = manager.Queue()
        # create a logger
        logger = logging.getLogger('app')
        # add a handler that uses the shared queue
        logger.addHandler(QueueHandler(queue))
        # log all messages, debug and up
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        # create the process pool with default configuration
        with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
            # issue a long running task to receive logging messages
            _ = pool.apply_async(logger_process, args=(queue,))
            # report initial message
            logger.info('Main process started.')
            # issue task to the process pool
            results = [pool.apply_async(task, args=(queue,)) for i in range(**2**)]
            # wait for all issued tasks to complete
            logger.info('Main process waiting...')
            for result in results:
                result.wait()
            # report final message
            logger.info('Main process done.')
            # shutdown the long running logger task
            queue.put(None)
            # close the process pool
            pool.close()
            # wait for all tasks to complete (e.g. the logger to close)
            pool.join()
```

Here I have two processes. One for logger processes. I have two workers which use the remaining process.It prints lines multiple times.

```
Logger process running.
 Main process started.
 Main process waiting...
 Child SpawnPoolWorker-2 starting.
 Child SpawnPoolWorker-2 step 0.
 Child SpawnPoolWorker-2 done.
 Child SpawnPoolWorker-2 starting.
 Child SpawnPoolWorker-2 starting.
 Child SpawnPoolWorker-2 step 0.
 Child SpawnPoolWorker-2 step 0.
 Child SpawnPoolWorker-2 done.
 Child SpawnPoolWorker-2 done.
 Main process done.
 Logger process shutting down.
```

Any time a process pool has fewer processes than a number of workers, it prints more lines. Not sure why ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is.  But don't you want to increase the pool size to 3 in the second example?  Only one of your workers is going to run.

Comment: Yes . It was just to show when the number of workers exceed the number of processes in the pool logging logs same line multiple times.